# Doctrine error when I try to validate my schema

Tags: php, symfony, doctrine-orm, doctrine

My problem is the next:

When I do "php app/console doctrine:schema:validate" throws this error:

[image]

Then when I see the code look like this:

[image]

By the way, this error ocurred when I moved my project from localhost( in my computer) to server. In my computer works perfectly.

Before, this error ocurred in other entity in the server and I had to removed the entity and create the new entity with "vi". Then, I copied the code into the new entity with the same name, so this way works but I not will like to make this for all my entities. I am using symfony 2.7.

I appreciate your help.

Comment: `column` needs to be `Column`

Comment: It would be prudent to type a copy of your code in future questions; much easier to read that way :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may have moved to *nix which is case sentive, so you should have a capital "C" on `@ORM\Column`.

```
@ORM\Column(type="string", length=6)
     ^
```

Always good to be accurate in the use of text case to be safe for both Windows or *nix environments.